# Refactor `yield None`

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, generator, yield

I wrote a generator function in Python 3.

Then I noticed that I do not use the values yielded by the generator. (I just call `next()` and ignore the result.) So I think I can replace all yields with `yield None`.

The next question: Should I refactor a generator which returns only nones into something other?

Maybe I can refactor my generator into a class and replace `yield None` with a dynamic method call? Is it always possible to refactor this way?

(The questions is probably not very hard, and I may try to answer my own question in coming minutes or hours.)

Comment: Opinion zone: I think it's fine to have a generator that doesn't yield meaningful values. The language devs must want us to be able to do that, or else they wouldn't have made it legal syntax to have a `yield` statement with no arguments.

Comment: What is the purpose of this generator? Why is it a generator at all? It's rather unusual to have a generator where you don't use the yielded values *or* `send` values in.

Comment: And what was the meaning of the values you were originally yielding?

Comment: The generator yielded files which my program loads during executing a cunny algorithm involving several (two) generator functions. I noticed that I can do processing (adding more scripts to the list of loaded scripts, `higherThan` relations between script precedences, etc.) of a newly loaded file in the generator itself, so I need to yield neither URL of the loaded file nor the result of parsing of the loaded file.

Comment: I looked up "cunny", and it didn't turn up anything except the vulgar slang term. Did you mean a different word?

Comment: Aside from that, 1) if you move the file processing into the generator, then it doesn't sound like there's any reason to keep it a generator instead of a regular function, and 2) it sounds like separating the jobs of finding the files and processing them may still be a worthwhile code-clarity reason to keep the processing out of that function.

Comment: @user2357112 I meant "cunning"

Comment: @user2357112 I use two generators (file loader and loaded scripts processor) intertwinningly. That is I define two generators and then write an algorithm which mixes both generators into a sequence of steps. This is the reason why I use generators, not regular functions. On "2)": I have a parser of the files as a separate class

Comment: After some thinking I concluded that rewriting an algorithm with a generator function (even returning nones) into a regular algorithm may be not quite trivial. However it would be hard to prove this.